# Qt - What should I use to implement multiple windows?

Tags: c++, qt

I've started learning Qt (C++) and I'm overwhelmed by the whole lot of component it has. I'm writing my first application and here's what it should look like:

1. When I run it, I have one main widget which has 8 QPushButtons.
2. When I click any of the buttons a 'window' should open and it should
   contain about 25-40 various labels, buttons, checkboxes, radio
   buttons and so on. So, I need 8 'windows'.

My question is: what should I use to implement these 'windows' - Widgets, Dialogs, MainWindows? What is like a conventional QT way of solving this problem?

Comment: The conventional developer's way to solve this (whatever that may be), is to read the documentation. Start with [Qt for Beginners](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Beginners). And, of course, take the [tour]. And make sure to read [ask].

Comment: Searching the web and some big hit the first matches... http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-gui-concepts.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want your application to look like.

If you want to have multible 'Windows' like different Tabs in your application then use [QStackedWidget Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) or [QTabWidget Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html).

If you need something like a Pop-Up you could use a QDialog.

Please make sure you understand how QWidget works and always take a look in the Qt Documentation.